# How do I customize Windows 10 Credential Provider using V2 CP Sample?

Tags: c++, windows, authentication, windows-10, credentials

I am currently trying to implement a custom credential provider on Windows 10 and I downloaded the V2 Credential Provider sample for Windows 8 from Microsoft.

I heard that there is little difference between windows 8's cp and that of Windows 10. 
so I tried this using v2 credential provider on Windows 10 notebook like below.

1. Compile source code and generate dll file
2. copy .dll file to system32
3. Run register.reg
4. Reboot

but I couldn't find any change on my Logon screen. 
How can I implement a new credential tile and what differences exist between windows 8 and 10's cp?

Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem and I want to share it for those having same problem.

*you can find information about Vista Credential provider from "Common Tasks for Extending SampleCredentialProvider" Section of the "Windows Vista Credential Provider Samples Overview UPDATE.docx" file(Microsoft)

I recommend that you check your computer'operating system whether 32 bits or 64 bits before extracting .dll file. If you have 64 bit one, you can solve the registration problem through x64 release.